# How to make legends independet of aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've managed to make the plot below using ggplot2 containing a boxplot, the observations and the weighted mean.

I managed to get the legend that i want by using the three different aesthetics fill, color and size, but I would like to produce the legend without using the aesthetics. Using the aesthetics make customization of the plot with regard to colors, fills and sized impossible and given I one day need a fourth element plotted, I'm running out of aesthetics.

Is there any way to treat legends individually on a "geom-basis" using the same aesthetics for all geoms?

More specifically I want to have the edges of the boxplot colored as fill, the observations colored as the boxplot and the weighted average colored black, but if I specidy these colors outside of the aes(), the legend is deleted or altered.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2) 

study <- c(1:10)
observations <- c(seq(10, 100, by = 10))
type <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
rate <- c(runif(10, 0, 1))

data1 <- data.frame(study, type, observations, rate)

average <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(rate = weighted.mean(rate, observations)) 

data1 %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = type, y = rate, fill = type), alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = type, y = rate, size = "Observations")) + 
  geom_point(data = average, 
             aes(x = type, y = rate, color = "Weighted mean"), 
             shape = 18, size = 5) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend"), 
         color = guide_legend(title = ""), 
         size = guide_legend(title = ""))
```

[image: Plot with desired legend]

Comment: Are you familiar with `scale_color_manual` / `scale_size_manual` / etc.? You can customize the desired color / size / and so on to mapped aesthetics that way.

Comment: No i wasn't, but thank you! That worked perfectly.